# Several figures with subplots using a combination list in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, combinations, subplot

I want to make a streamplot of a vectorial field which contains some free constants which I would like to change. So I've made combinations of these constants and I can sucessfully plot the stream plots one by one with this:

```
Y, X = np.mgrid[-1:10:200j, 0:10:200j]

tau_x = [0.01, 0.1, 1., 10.]
tau_y = [0.01, 0.1, 1., 10.]
alpha = [0.01, 0.1, 1., 10.]
r = [0.1, 0.01, 0.001]
K = [0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5]

combinations_list = list(itertools.product(tau_x,tau_y,alpha,r,K))

for a in combinations_list:

    (tau_x, tau_y, alpha, r, K) = a

    Fx = (1/tau_x) * ( (-8/3)*(2*r-alpha)*(X-1) + K*X )
    Fy = (2/(tau_y*X**(3/2))) * ( -2*(Y-1) + 3*Y*(X-1)/X + K*X*Y )

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    strm = ax.streamplot(X, Y, Fx, Fy, linewidth=0.5)

    plt.show()
```

Now, because we are talking of a very large number of combinations, I would like to make a figure with subplots (say 9 each figure but it could be more) which would reduce a lot the number of figures.

Note: I am interested in seeing one figure each time and that's why plt.show() is inside the loop to avoid opening all figures at once.

EDIT: Following ImportanceOfBeingErnest sugestion I changed the code to

```
Y, X = np.mgrid[-1:10:200j, 0:10:200j]

tau_x = [0.01, 0.1, 1., 10.]
tau_y = [0.01, 0.1, 1., 10.]
alpha = [0.01, 0.1, 1., 10.]
r = [0.1, 0.01, 0.001]
K = [0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5]

combinations_list = list(itertools.product(tau_x,tau_y,alpha,r,K))
length = len(combinations_list)

N = 9 #number of subplots per figure

for i in range(0,100):

    subset = combinations_list[9*i:9*i+9]

    fig = plt.figure()

    j = 1
    for a in subset:

        (tau_x, tau_y, alpha, r, K) = a

        Fx = (1/tau_x) * ( (-8/3)*(2*r-alpha)*(X-1) + K*X )
        Fy = (2/(tau_y*X**(3/2))) * ( -2*(Y-1) + 3*Y*(X-1)/X + K*X*Y )

        ax = fig.add_subplot(3,3,j)
        ax.streamplot(X, Y, Fx, Fy, linewidth=0.5)
        ++j


    plt.show()
```

but it's only plotting the first one of each subset and in a weird way with colors in the vectors.

Comment: You can use two loops. One selects the subset of combination you want to show per figure, the other loops over this subset and plots each in its own subplot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've followed your sugestion as you can see in EDIT, but still having problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating `j` correctly. `++j` doesn't update the value of `j`. Your code will work fine if you replace `++j` by `j += 1` or `j = j+1`. Both are equivalent.

```
for i in range(0,100):
    subset = combinations_list[9*i:9*i+9]
    fig = plt.figure()

    j = 1
    for a in subset:
        (tau_x, tau_y, alpha, r, K) = a

        Fx = (1/tau_x) * ( (-8/3)*(2*r-alpha)*(X-1) + K*X )
        Fy = (2/(tau_y*X**(3/2))) * ( -2*(Y-1) + 3*Y*(X-1)/X + K*X*Y )

        ax = fig.add_subplot(3,3,j)
        ax.streamplot(X, Y, Fx, Fy, linewidth=0.5)
        j += 1 # <--- change here
```

[image]